# onclick event function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, event-driven

I have some JavaScript code in an HTML page with a button. I have a function called `click()` that handles the `onClick` event of the button. The code for the button is as follows:

```
<input type="button" onClick="click()">button text</input>
```

The problem is that when the button is clicked, the function is not called. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you getting an error in the console? Can you post the click function. It works for me **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/gTqnV/)**

Comment: I think you need a semicolon after the function like this: `<input type="button" onClick="click();">button text</input>`

Comment: Try... `onclick="javascript:click();"`

Comment: onclick already assumes its JavaScript.  you would only use javascript:click(); if you were setting an href for a link.  Also the semicolon isn't needed unless a 2nd function was being called as well.

Comment: where did you declare/put the click() function? Is it in the right scope?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Two observations:

1. You should write

   ```
   <input type="button" value="button text" />
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   <input type="button">button text</input>
   ```
2. You should rename your function. The function `click()` is already defined on a button (it simulates a click), and gets a higher priority then your method.

Note that there are a couple of suggestions here that are plain wrong, and you shouldn't spend to much time on them:

- Do not use `onclick="javascript:myfunc()"`. Only use the `javascript:` prefix inside the `href` attribute of a hyperlink: `<a href="javascript:myfunc()">`.
- You don't have to end with a semicolon. `onclick="foo()"` and `onclick="foo();"` both work just fine.
- Event attributes in HTML are not case sensitive, so `onclick`, `onClick` and `ONCLICK` all work. It is common practice to write attributes in lowercase: `onclick`. *note that javascript itself is case sensitive, so if you write `document.getElementById("...").onclick = ...`, then it **must** be all lowercase*.

Comment: this is just a sample script im writing on my Windows 95 with IE5 so i'm not using any DOM stuff because i don't know how well it's supported. I will try that out though. Thanks

Comment: yeah i just had to change the name of my function and it worked. Thanks again! i was really stuck

Comment: @ElianEbbing Thanks for taking the time to explain a few of these things... as small as they are, they really helped me understand what I was doing wrong.

Comment: @ElianEbbing http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/gs6rehnx/4/ .... could you see this it has same problem

Comment: @hitesh No, this is a different problem: JSFiddle puts all the javascript code within `$(window).load(function() { ... })`. This means that `test()` is not globally accessible. If you change the dropdown on the left from `onLoad` to `No wrap` then your example should work in JSFiddle.

Comment: thanks that worked : one more question -- are we not supposed to use document.ready in jsfiddle?

Comment: I had same problem using a function called "submit()". Changing name worked.

Answer (score 17):

click() is a reserved word and already a function, change the name from click() to runclick() it works fine

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
<input type="button" onClick="return click();">button text</input>
```

Answer (score 3):

Check you are calling same function or not.

```
<script>function greeting(){document.write("hi");}</script>

<input type="button" value="Click Here" onclick="greeting();"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try fixing the capitalization. `onclick` instead of `onClick`

Reference: [Mozilla Developer Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onclick)

Comment: Your link is a XUL link. This is what you want: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onclick

Comment: all capitalizations work, the browser shouldn't care if it's onClick, ONCLICK, onclick, Onclick, or anything else. i prefer camel notation, so i use that

Comment: You're right. Javascript is case sensitive, which may be the source of my confusion.

Comment: even the doc on mdn is use all lowercase, you write your confusion on other people question, that's not good

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do:
    `<input type="button" value="button text" onclick="click()">`
Hope this helps you!

Comment: I think the issue is his 'onclick' property, not the way the text value is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
//$(document).ready(function () {
function showcontent() {
        document.getElementById("demo22").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
//});// end of ready function
</script>
```

I had the same problem where onclick function calls would not work. I had included the function inside the usual "$(document).ready(function(){});" block used to wrap jquery scripts. Commenting this block out solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should change the name of your function. Javascript has reserved methods and onclick = >>>> click() <<<< is one of them so just rename it, add an 's' to the end of it or something.
*strong text*`

Answer (score 0):

Today this also happened to me. The function name maybe conflicts with keywords. My case is `scrape()`. I change the function name, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause for an item not responding to an event is when the item is overlapped by another.
In that case, you may have to set a higher [`z-index`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) for the item you wish to click on.