# javascript onclick not working in jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, jsfiddle

I am trying to make jsfiddle , my onclick is not working in jsfiddle. what is wrong in my code

```
<input value="press" type="button" onclick="myclick()">


function myclick(){
   alert("myclick")
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/gs6rehnx/11/

### EDIT

I tried `No wrap - In head` and tried again with `document.ready` it is not working in jsfiddle again

```
ERROR - Uncaught ReferenceError: myclick is not defined
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/33wLs160/6/

I have checked with already existing question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453937/onclick-event-not-working-in-javascript) but my problem is happening when I am trying it in jsfiddle

Can some one please help me ....thanks

Comment: In the options on the left, choose "No wrap - in <head>/<body>". http://jsfiddle.net/33wLs160/

Comment: could you please check this @JoshCrozier - http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/33wLs160/6/

Comment: You could omit the `$(document).ready(...)` wrapper http://jsfiddle.net/Ldoumrhz/

Comment: if I want to keep `$(document).ready(...)` How do I use it

Comment: @hitesh — Why would you want to keep that? It is used for running code when the DOM is ready. There is no reason for you to want to wait until the DOM is ready before defining that function!

Comment: so are you saying no need to use `$(document).ready(...)` in jsfiddle ?

Comment: JSFiddle has nothing to do with it. There's no need to use `ready` for the code you have written.

Answer (score 12):

You need to select *No library (pure JS)* and *No wrap - in head*. Then it will work as a simple HTML with javascript page.

This will be inserted in a `<script>` element in the `<head>`:

```
function myclick(){
  alert("myclick")
}
```

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gs6rehnx/14/)

Comment: But it needs both, No wrap and No library to work. Even No wrap - in body is enough too. What is important is the No library (pure JS).

Comment: I am not saying that jQuery is stopping it working, but it is not required.

Comment: That is **exactly** what you were saying. Quote: "But it needs both, No wrap and No library to work". No Library means not loading jQuery.

Comment: You are right. I interpreted your first comment wrong. I was interpreting the *I tried No wrap - In head and tried again with document.ready it is not working in jsfiddle* as if the OP was using the `$(document).ready` too.

Answer (score 4):

As others said, for first case you have to set `No wrap - in <head>` or `No wrap - in <body>` as javascript panel settings (the blue link at js panel top-right).

For the second (your Edit) question, your code inside a function and the js will run it (within a new context), but it will do nothing as you just define a function and ignore it without any call or assignment.

if you call alert(myclick) you will see all the code is executed and its defined at that point. [see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/33wLs160/27/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  //alert("ready is executed");

  function myclick(){
    alert("myclick is called")
    window.location.reload(true);
  }

  alert(myclick); //this will show the myclick is a defined function!

  //document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].onclick = myclick;
})
```

if you call this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].onclick = myclick;
```

in that `$(document).ready({...})` scope, it will be assigned to the button and works as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Select "No wrap - bottom of " in "Load Type" of the scripting panel.
This is the solution for Jsfiddle (till 17 december 2019).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<input value="press" id='a' type="button">
document.getElementById('a').onclick = function() { alert(1); }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gs6rehnx/12/

Comment: i want to give onclick in html

Comment: @hitesh — Why? This is 2014, not 1998.

Comment: just wanted to know why  it happened ... thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

This one is working. Just remove it from document ready event. Also semicolons are optional in javascript but i advice to use them.

```js
function myclick() {
    alert("myclick");
    window.location.reload(true);
}
```

```html
<input value="press" type="button" onclick="myclick();">
<script>
    alert("home");
</script>
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/33wLs160/9/).