# on button click with confirm alert box, query submitting on cancel also

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, sql

i have created a button to remove data from database. The button code looks like the following:

```html
<form method="post">
  <button name="remove" onclick="myFunction()" style="margin-left: -15%; border-radius: 15px;" class="button button2">Remove</button>
</form>
```

i have given an alert confirm box to proceed or cancel the button click.

```js
function myFunction() {
  confirm("Do you want to remove?!");
}
```

now after the button click, if i do cancel or if i do ok, both are executing the query. the cancel button is not cancelling the click. can anyone please tell what is wrong here.

Comment: hard to be sure without seeing more code but perhaps `return confirm("Do you want to remove?!");` will work

Comment: What you are doing is correct .. you just need to return the value of confirm -----     `return confirm("Do you want to remove?!");`   Read more at https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Way 1:
you can use this:

```
  <button name="remove" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" style="margin-left: -15%; border-radius: 15px;" class="button button2">Remove</button>
```

the `return` is very important

---

WAY 2:

```
function myFunction() {
     if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
           //Do SomeThing...!
     }
}
```

---

NOTE:

You can use the [Sweet Alert](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#examples)

Answer (score 1):

You need to validate the confirm response

```js
function myFunction() {
  if (confirm("Do you want to remove?!")) {
    //do stufff here...
    console.log('success')
  } else {
    console.log('cancel')
  }
}
```

```html
<button name="remove" onclick="myFunction()"class="button button2">Remove</button>
```

Comment: can you post that used code with fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: this one wont work See in action even with alert https://jsfiddle.net/am5kjbo2/1/ You didnt save @prasanth nothingin your link

Comment: @Dilek .its working .In jsfiddle its add the script before the html like inside the `head` tag [see this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26329761/javascript-onclick-not-working-in-jsfiddle).so its undefined while cllick.[see this another fiddle working result](https://jsbin.com/maceboluge/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: @prasanth sorry but didnt work on for me and still doesnt in MOBILE here is jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/am5kjbo2/2/ even when I open this site in mboile version

Comment: @Dilek.i already posted my above comment please read.jsfiddle is a problem not with code, try with jsbin like https://jsbin.com/maceboluge/edit?html,js,console,output  .or else create own html and paste the script  tag after button then try your mobile

Comment: @prasanth I see its working on jsbin and need to include js react to to make it works on jsfiddle Sorry didnt notice jsFiddle problem

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you do preventDefault because your delete button is inside the form

```js
document.getElementById("uniqueId").addEventListener("click", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  if(confirm("Msg")){
    //do something
  }
});
```

```html
<form method="post">
  <button name="remove" id="uniqueId"  style=" border-radius: 15px;" class="button button2">Remove</button>
</form>
```

Make sure that every button have a unique id