# Javascript Clear Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button, canvas

I have a button to clear the drawings of my canvas element as follows:

```
<button id="button_clear" onclick="clear()" > Clear ! </button>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
```

Clear function is like that :

```
function clear(){

  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  ctx.beginPath();

}
```

However when I click on the clear button, my function does not do anything at all.

Comment: try to change your function name, for example `clearCanvas()`

Comment: that worked, thanks.

Comment: your are welcome! I left it as an answer for further usage, better accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to avoid using function names something like `click()`, `clear()`, ...
Change your function name and check if it works.
Check this answer for more detail information
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5454341/5344661