# "onclick" event is not triggering on image to change it

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<script>
    function click()
    {
        var username = prompt("Enter ur name:");
        if(username)
        {
            alert("Hi,"+username);
            document.getElementById("rockPic").src = "rocksmile.jpg";
        }
    }

</script>
```

```
    <img id = "rockPic" 
    align = "center"; 
    src = "rock.jpg";
    alt = "irock"; 
    height = 200px; 
    width = 200px;
    style = "cursor:pointer";
    onclick = "click();">

</body>
```

In this code while clicking on the image then 'prompt' box must be displayed. But it is doing nothing. please help!

Comment: Have your checked your browser console for errors? Chances are you cannot use `click` as a function name.

Comment: try changing the function name to something other than `click` - it will work then

Comment: Yaa but it doesn't showing any errors.

Comment: Looks like the HTML is not correct. Why are there semicolons after each attribute value?...
```<img id = "rockPic" align = "center" src = "rock.jpg" alt = "irock" height = "200px" width = "200px" style = "cursor:pointer;" onclick = "click();">```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onclick event not working in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453937/onclick-event-not-working-in-javascript)

Comment: I got it after changing the fuction name.. Thank you @JaromandaX

Comment: @Johannes, there shouldn't be. And yet, there are in the question's HTML part.

Comment: @Catalyst Yes, I misunderstood your comment - You are right. sorry about that (deleted my previous comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`click` is a native javascript function already. It simulates a mouse click. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click

Use a different name for your function.

PS - your tag has a bunch of syntax errors. Remove the `;`'s and `height` and `width` doesn't need units, just numbers, and `align` is obsolete on an `img` in html5.

```html
<script>
  function myFunc() {
    var username = prompt("Enter ur name:");
    if (username) {
      alert("Hi," + username);
      document.getElementById("rockPic").src = "rocksmile.jpg";
    }
  }
</script>

<img id="rockPic" src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" alt="irock" height="200" width="200" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="myFunc()">
```

Comment: `click is a reserved word in javascript` - that doesn't sound right, never seen that in a list of reserved words - that link shows that the click method on an element does things, that doesn't show it's a reserved word

Comment: @JaromandaX you're probably right, I just mean it's reserved already as a native function. updated my wording.

Comment: Because it's not a reserved word, it's already defined on buttons.

Comment: I would also like to suggest removing the semicolon's from the end of the `img` attributes.

Comment: @NewToJS thanks, didn't even look at all the syntax errors in that tag! updated

Comment: @PeterMader - `it's already defined on buttons` - but there are no buttons

Comment: @MichaelCoker Very welcome. It appears most people aren't paying much attention to the image tag. Every answer posted so far has failed to remove them :p

Comment: @NewToJS hah yeah, probably because it's not really relevant to the question and it works with those errors (in the browsers I tested anyways)

Comment: @JaromandaX You're right. I meant [`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click).

Answer (score 0):

Using a different function name and an image that is actually accessible, it works here:

```js
function my_function()
    {
        var username = prompt("Enter ur name:");
        if(username)
        {
            alert("Hi,"+username);
            document.getElementById("rockPic").src = "http://placehold.it/200x200/d95";
        }
    }
```

```html
<img id = "rockPic" 
    align = "center"
    src = "rock.jpg"
    alt = "irock"
    height = "200px" 
    width = "200px"
    style = "cursor:pointer;"
    onclick = "my_function();">
```

Comment: I would like to suggest removing the semicolon's from the end of the `img` attributes

Answer (score 0):

Per documentation, the string values of "onClick" handler attributes are interpreted as the bodies of handler functions. Now since, there is already a function called 'click' for calling the event handler, declaring another function with the same name will basically override the native click.

```js
 function clickAction()
  {
        var username = prompt("Enter ur name:");
        if(username)
        {
            alert("Hi,"+username);
            document.getElementById("rockPic").src = "rocksmile.jpg";
        }
    }
```

```html
   <img id = "rockPic" 
    align = "center" 
    src = "rock.jpg"
    alt = "irock" 
    height = 200px
    width = 200px
    style = "cursor:pointer"
    onclick = "clickAction()">
```

Comment: I would like to suggest removing the semicolon's from the end of the `img` attributes. People don't seem to be paying attention to the source code given.

Comment: @NewToJS Good catch.!